# How do I forward fill missing columns in pandas so no dates are missing

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like so

```
industries     2020-08-19    2020-08-21    2020-08-22    2020-08-26
banking        0.3           0.41          0.14          0.23
energy         0.25          0.28          0.33          0.37
telecom.       0.11          0.32          0.14          0.19
```

How can I forward fill the dates columns? For example I'm missing the column 2020-08-20, how can I create a new column and fill it with the values from the last time there was a value?

I'm very new to pandas so sorry if this is a simple problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
# we want to work with date columns only
df = df.set_index('industries')

# change to datetime type
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)

# interpolate and fill:
df.T.asfreq('D').ffill().T
```

Comment: wow didn't know about T or asfreq(). I thought I had to do some kind of pivot thanks random stranger